# MySQL TIME vs DECIMAL

Tags: mysql

I want to store in DB `START time` and `END time`. Important are only `hours` and `minutes`, so in form user have 4 dropdowns (start_time_hours, start_time_minutes, end_time_hours, end_time_minutes).
Values for hours - [00-23], for minutes - [00, 15, 30, 45]. At the end I would like to have substraction from both in decimal.

I'm wondering **is it better to store 2 TIME fields (for start and end time) or 2 DECIMAL fields?**

In this case minutes can be smoothly converted to decimal: 
[00 => 00, 15 => 0.25, 30 => 0.5, 45 => 0.75], so time 19:15 would turn out as 19.25.
I guess DB storage-wise it's the same, - as TIME and DECIMAL(4,2) both takes up 3 bytes, if I'm not wrong :)

So, for example, after saving data to DB, I go back to edit the form and expect the saved values to be in those 4 dropdowns. If DB data would be TIME type, then I should use something like

> `$hours = date('G', strtotime($start_time))` && `$minutes = date('i', strtotime($start_time))`

for START time dropdowns, but if data would be DECIMAL, then

> `$hours = floor($start_time);` && `$minutes = $start_time - $hours;`

**Which of these 2 ways would be faster?**

It could be some other kind of calculations between these 2 times, so I guess for all of those for TIME type data it would involve `date()` or(and) `strtotime()` functions, but for DECIMAL type only mathematical functions? 
So, which solution would be best for speed and DB? Maybe there is even better solution for this case?

I guess one disadvantage for DECIMAL is scalabilty in the future, for exapmle if we decide to let user choose minutes from 1-60, - then we can't get precise DECIMAL for 18:10, as it would be 18.16666...

Comment: I question whether storing time by itself is really sufficient for what you are trying to do.  For example, is there ever a chance that some event could start at say 11pm and then continue over to the next day?  If so, then you would be much better off just storing full dates.

Comment: if you want to get bothered by minutes to percent conversions with the lose of precisions and being able to give wrong result, go for decimal. If you prefer to easier handle times, go for time. a 3rd option could be to store minutes only. 630 being in example 10:30. (minutes / 60) hours (minutes % 60) minutes

Comment: MySQL allows you to subtract time. Why would you want to store it as decimal then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand and it's a good point, but in this case the requirement is that it won't be between 2 dates.

Comment: @Cid Ty, that 3rd option saves 1 byte in DB (if using smallint), but it could also add more calculations, for example, in that editing-form phase for dropdowns it should be $hours = floor($start_time/60); && $minutes = $start_time - $hours; (1 extra division :) )

Comment: @SalmanA That's what I want to find out which would be better. Aren't MySQL date (as well as PHP date) functions/manipulations slower than numeric manipulations?

Comment: @Gaccho I would not worry about slow as long as data is stored the way it should be. Besides, storing data in the wrong datatype could cause of slowness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the TIME type. The time type is more meaningful. Maybe decimal type is little faster than TIME type sometimes.
But when you using decimal, you should ensure that everyone calculate rightly on everywhere, not just on your code. I think that is more important than size and speed.